# Getting the name attribute of an HTML element and sending it to the server

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, flask

I trying to send the name attribute of an element to the server

So the user would click on an  element and I would send its name to the server.
I am using flask.

Right now I have this JS function that selects the elements name and stores it in a variable:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    let x = $(this).attr('name');
    console.log(x);

  });
});
```

Here is my code on the server:

```
@app.route('/friends_Profile', methods=["GET"])
def friends_profile():
    name = request.args.get('x')
    print(name)



    return render_template('friends-profile.html', friend=name)
```

the name variable is empty (None)

And here is the HTML:

```
<div class='friends'>
            <b>You are Friends with:</b>
            {% for x in range(friends|length) %}
            <li><a id='{{loop.index}}'
            method="GET"  href="/friends_Profile" name='{{friends[loop.index-1][0][0]}}_{{friends[loop.index-1][0][1]}}' value="{{number[loop.index -1][0]}}">{{friends[loop.index -1][0][0]}} {{friends[loop.index -1][0][1]}}</a></li>

            {% endfor %}

      </div>
```

Comment: What is the question? You can do `$.get("/friends_Profile?x="+x,function(res) { console.log(res)});`

Comment: Not sure what your problem is: use `$.ajax` (since you're already using jQuery) to call your server route, passing the `x=name` as the query string.

Comment: I am still confused... how do I get the value of x to appear in the friends_profile() function on my server? request.args.get('x') returns None

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this...via Traveling Tech Guy's comments in your question. Send your 'x' var to the server using .ajax...can do whatever you want with it after that.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("a").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        let x = $(this).attr('name');
        console.log(x);

        var url_to_server = "http://localhost/server_response.[php or whatever]?name=x";
        jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url_to_server,
                cache: false,
                success: function(response)
                {
                console.log("sent it to server - update view if needed");
                }
           });
      });
    });
```